# webpack-dev-server configuration problems

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to make configuration for my project starter kit. My supposed project structure looks like this:


....................................................
dist
----bundle.js

node_modules...
----
----

src
----main.js

index.html

package.json

webpack.config.js

....................................................

My webpack configurations looks like this:


package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack_starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
console.log("test");
```

I'm trying to configure webpack so it can extract everything in dist/ directory from src/, watch changes in src/ and override changed in src/ files in dist/, after changing it should reload browser.

What's wrong with my configuration (dev server only runs and doesn't compile anything) and how to fix it?

Comment: any error thrown in console?

Comment: Nope, everything fine.

Comment: that means it should have generated bundle.js file. which has not been generated in your case. right?